# NeurIPS author information for many authors

Tags: author

Based on what I've seen in recent NeurIPS papers, it seems like there is a standard format for author information when there are many authors and multiple institutions. For example, how would you reproduce the author info shown below, which appeared in a paper from last year's conference?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[final]{neurips_2022}`.  The rest was done by the original writer "by hand" using LaTeX `\author`.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[final]{neurips_2022}

\title{Learning Space Partitions for Path Planning}

\author{%
Kevin Yang$^{1*}$ \quad Tianjun Zhang$^{1*}$ \quad Chris Cummins$^2$ \quad Brandon Cui$^2$ \quad Benoit Steiner$^2$ \\
\textbf{Linnan Wang}$^3$ \quad \textbf{Joseph E. González}$^1$ \quad \textbf{Dan Klein}$^1$ \quad \textbf{Yuandong Tiang}$^2$\\
$^1$UC Berkeley \quad $^2$Facebook AI Research \quad $^3$Brown University\\
\texttt{\{yangk,tianjunz,jegonzal,klein\}@berkeley.edu}\\
\texttt{\{cummins,bcui,benoitsteiner,yuandongt\}@fb.com}\\
\texttt{linnan\_wang@brown.edu}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

See [source files](https://arxiv.org/e-print/2106.10544)